# How to create / update a Backbone View based on a response from a Backbone Model?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've found a ton of Backbone examples dealing with lists of items. I'm trying to find a way to accomplish the following:

1. Update the latest price of an item (pulled from a server call) along with other information about the item (also from the server.. same API call)
2. If the price has changed, call some other function

Seems simple, I know. I can handle the server API, but I'm a bit lost with the Backbone aspect. I'm new to Backbone, so please bear with me.

I've figured out my model should be something like:

```
  var Item_m = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/welcome/item'
  });
```

and I can instantiate the model and put a `.fetch()` in a `setInterval`. But the rest escapes me for now.

My `/welcome/item/1` returns: `{"id":1,"price":121}` by the way.

I can successfully get the data, I just don't know how to tie it in with a `View` in backbone.

Comment: Have you tried listening for `"change"` events from the model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I can listen for the `change` event and trigger an event, but how do I tie that into a `View`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone is an event-driven framework, every object it defines can `listenTo` or `trigger` events. This is how components communicate in a Backbone application ( [Built-in events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) ) . With that in mind, everytime a `Backbone.Model`'s attribute changes, it triggers a `change:[attribute-name]` event. You can bind any number of functions to this event.

Here is an example going from instantiation to showing ( [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamor/2V8K3/) ):

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: '/welcome/item' });

var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

  // Very minimal example template for an item
  template: _.template('<a href="#/item/<%= id %>"> <%= price %> </a>'),

  initialize: function() {
    // Calls the views render on model change
    this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render );

    // Calls special function for price change
    this.listenTo( this.model, 'change:price', this.onPriceChange );

    return this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    // Populate the view's DOM element with the compiled template reflecting the model
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.attributes) );
    return this;
  },

  onPriceChange: function() {
    // Do something special for price change, maybe trigger a global event?
    Backbone.trigger('item:price:change', this.model );
  }
});

var item = new Item({ id : 1 });
item.fetch();
var itemView = new ItemView({ model : item });

// Insert the view's element inside the DOM
$('#item-placeholder').append( itemView.el );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can structure the view and model in the following way:

```
var Item_m = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/welcome/item'
  });

var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
         this.model = new Item_m ();
         this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);   
         /*Can setup the periodic pull using Backbone.poller.*/
         //https://github.com/uzikilon/backbone-poller

    },

    render: function() {
         //Do UI rendering stuffs   
    }
}); 


var itemVieww = new ItemView ();
```